# Managing Large Database Entity Models

Tags: entity-framework

I would like hear how other's are effectively (or not) working with the Visual Studio Entity Designer when many database tables exists.  It seems to me that navigating the Designer is tough enough to find what you are looking for with just a few tables but how about a database with say 100 to 200 tables?  When a table change is made at the database level how is the model updated?  Does it overwrite any manual changes you have made to the model?  How would you quickly find an entity in the designer to make a change or inspect a change?   Seems unrealistic to be scrolling around looking for specific entity.

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to say we have a fairly large number of tables  (52), and i don't have major issues navigating the model, I would be more concerned with EF internally not being able to scale.

I don't use the designer i use the [Model browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bb738483(v=vs.100)).  There is a feature in the model browser called "Show in Designer" which can take you to any table you are searching for.

[image: link text]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC176600.gif))</sub>

In all honesty i use the Model browser more than i do the Designer.  From the browser you can set pretty much anything (table mappings/ table properties).

When it comes time to update, it does not affect your conceptual model(any manual changes).  Unless of course you have removed something from your physical model and it can no longer map.

Comment: Nice thanks!  Wondering if other's share your concern about scalability and the Entity Framework.